# Performance jQuery Ajax load game sources display as modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, performance

I have a base website system which is using ajax load content without refreshing pages. I have a game page that load many html5 game links via ajax json and when I click on any games it will load the game source files which display as pop up. I am wonder while I'm playing then if I click the close button for stopping the game and then I remove the element of the source files game. Will it free up the memory? As I have noticed, it seems to getting slow the broswer. Anyone has experienced with that, please share with me.

**Note:** I need some suggestions in order to remove the elements and free up the memory.

eg:

```
<div id="pop-up">
<a id="close" href="#">Close Button</a>
<div id="inner-pop-up">
    <script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="game">
        <canvas></canvas>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
$('#pop-up').modal('view', {
    speed: 750,
    close: '.close-favourite',
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    animation: 'top',
    position: 'center',
    overlayClose: true
});
$('#close').on('click', function() {
    $('#inner-pop-up').children().remove();
});
```

Comment: `<script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>` three times? Why?  I think we need to see the code (all of it including the ajax part) to determine more here.

Comment: its the files that I loaded from ajax bro, the thing is that I want to know the way to free up the memory when I click close button and remove the elements from ajax.
eg:
here are the files that I loaded from ajax
 <script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="game sources" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="game">
        <canvas></canvas>
       </div>
   </div>
then I click the close button and remove them.

Comment: So are you saying that this is NOT your actual code for that the `src="game sources"` and that is NOT your actual URI specification and only a representation?  This is important to know.  If that is the case then it becomes important to know what that script contains as any memory leaks would be within those code segments. IF for instance those code segments load a second copy of jQuery then that would leak memory.  It would also be important to see your ACTUAL ajax code.  Nothing in this code is ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real way to free up any resources used by script functions is to add a JavaScript file that basically calls delete window.myFunction for every possible object and function (functions are objects really) your specified script files may define. **To me, for obvious reasons, this is a really bad idea.**

Note that these objects would be script (window) objects so you cannot use `.remove()` to remove those.

I would also note that your should use `$('#inner-pop-up').empty();` rather than your `$('#inner-pop-up').children().remove();` since that would remove the text of the element if any, as well and specifically removes the data and event handlers from those elements prior to removal from the DOM.

You might have some very specific functions and objects from your scripts that you might want to remove here but only the contents of your scripts would tell that.  If you create global window objects that gets really messy fast.

Note it is REALLY hard to determine what a script file creates and then remove it.

To prove a point open up your favorite browser console and execute  `$("script").remove().` stuff in that script still runs.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Schultheiss for answered. 

**Note it is REALLY hard to determine what a script file creates and then remove it.** 
To answer your, these are the game file that contained many objects in there.

Your Point: **To prove a point open up your favorite browser console and execute  $("script").remove(). stuff in that script still runs.**

You gave me a clear point. So what are the solution to remove that?

Comment: If you re-use the same objects it should not be an issue.  If you create new objects, you can possibly set them to `null` value as: `var myobj ="howdy"; myobj=null;`  So for your specific instance try `FootballChallenge=null;` or do the same for any instances of that.

Answer (score 0):

Eg: This is my game file which contained the object like that

```
FootballChallenge.Game = function (game) {
    FootballChallenge._scoreText = null;
    FootballChallenge._score = 0;
    FootballChallenge.kickBoard;
    this._preventClick = true;
    FootballChallenge.kaboomGroup;
    FootballChallenge.ball;
    FootballChallenge.shoe;
    FootballChallenge.self;
};

FootballChallenge.Game.prototype = {  

create: function () {       
    FootballChallenge.self = this.game;
    this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);       
    this.game.physics.arcade.checkCollision.up = false;

    this.bg = this.game.add.image(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'field');
    this.bg.anchor.setTo(0.5);

    FootballChallenge.kickBoard =  this.game.add.sprite(10, 20, 'kickBoard');       
    FootballChallenge._scoreText = this.game.add.bitmapText(0, FootballChallenge.kickBoard.height/2 + 20, 'white-font', ''+FootballChallenge._score+'', 32);        
    FootballChallenge._scoreText.align = 'center';      
    FootballChallenge._scoreText.x = (FootballChallenge.kickBoard.width-FootballChallenge._scoreText.width + 20)/2;     

    FootballChallenge.ball = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY - 100, 'ball');
    this.game.physics.arcade.enable(FootballChallenge.ball);
    FootballChallenge.ball.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    FootballChallenge.ball.scale.setTo(0.5);        
    FootballChallenge.ball.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    FootballChallenge.ball.body.gravity.y = 0;
    FootballChallenge.ball.body.bounce.setTo(1);

    FootballChallenge.shoe = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'shoe');
    this.game.physics.arcade.enable(FootballChallenge.shoe);
    FootballChallenge.shoe.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    FootballChallenge.shoe.scale.setTo(0.5);
    FootballChallenge.shoe.body.setSize(130,50,0,20);       
    FootballChallenge.shoe.body.collideWorldBounds = true;      

    FootballChallenge.kaboomGroup = this.game.add.group();
    FootballChallenge.kaboomGroup.createMultiple(10, 'kaboom');
    FootballChallenge.kaboomGroup.forEach(this.explosion, this);        

    this.play();        
},

explosion: function(kick) {
    kick.anchor.x = 0.7;
    kick.anchor.y = 0.5;
    kick.animations.add('kaboom');
},

play: function() {
    this.bitmask = this.game.make.bitmapData(this.game.width, this.game.height);
    this.bitmask.fill(50,50,50);        
    this.mask = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, this.bitmask);
    this.mask.tint = 0x000000;
    this.mask.alpha = 0.6;
    this.game.paused = true;        
    var pausedText = this.game.add.bitmapText(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY - 200, 'white-font', 'click anywhere to begin!', 32);    
    pausedText.align = 'center';
    pausedText.tint = 0xff0e25;
    pausedText.anchor.setTo(0.5);       
    this.game.input.onDown.add(function(){          
        pausedText.destroy();           
        this.game.paused = false;
        this.mask.alpha = 0;
        FootballChallenge.ball.body.gravity.y = 1500;           
        this.game.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
    }, this);
},

countScore: function(ball, shoe) {      
    ball.body.velocity.y = -1000;
    ball.body.gravity.x = FootballChallenge.self.rnd.integerInRange(-80, 80);
    FootballChallenge._scoreText.setText(FootballChallenge._score +=1);
    FootballChallenge._scoreText.x = (FootballChallenge.kickBoard.width-FootballChallenge._scoreText.width + 20)/2;

    var boom = FootballChallenge.kaboomGroup.getFirstExists(false);
    boom.reset(shoe.x, shoe.y);
    boom.play('kaboom', 40, false, true);

},

lose: function() {      
    this.game.state.start('EndGame');       
},

update: function() {
    if(FootballChallenge.ball.y >= this.game.height - 100) {
        FootballChallenge.ball.body.gravity = false;
        this.game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 0.2, this.lose, this);          
    }
    this.game.physics.arcade.collide(FootballChallenge.ball, FootballChallenge.shoe, this.countScore);
    this.game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(FootballChallenge.shoe, 30, this.game.input.activePointer, 50);        
}

};
```